# Enhanced ecommerce for UA or ecommerce for G4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

Hoping for some advice please. I need to setup ecommerce tracking on my company website. Is it better to setup Enhanced e-commerce tracking for UA, or the new Google Analytics 4 setup? Struggling with pros and cons, as it appears G4 is the way forward but still missing a lot of functionality.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the enhanced ecommerce of Universal Analytics you certainly know which is the optimal setup, that of GA4 may be subject to subsequent adjustments. The advice is always the same, which is to use both in parallel so that we have the data as we know it and start tracking with the new method.